# JAX-RS client inside a container ISO8601 date serialization

Tags: json, rest, jakarta-ee, jackson, jax-rs

I have a JSON REST API featuring a `POST /items` endpoint, which expects an object like:

`{"name": "item_name", "timestamp": "2018-01-01T01:01:01.001"}`

I need to call this endpoint from a JEE7 application deployed on WildFly10.

To model the object in Java I defined a simple DTO class:

```
class ItemDTO {

  private String name;
  private LocalDateTime timestamp;

  // default constructor and getters/setters omitted for brevity
}
```

By default, serialization of LocalDateTime results into a complex JSON object instead of a ISO8601 string.

Following what I found on the web, I added to my dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

With `jackson.version = 2.7.4`

```
ClientBuilder builder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
  .register(new RequestLogger())
  .register(
    new JacksonJsonProvider(
      new ObjectMapper()
        .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule()) 
        .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
        .configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DURATIONS_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false)
        .setDateFormat(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
      , DEFAULT_ANNOTATIONS)
);
```

The code above configures a clientBuilder to build clients equipped with a ObjectMapper that will serialize Java8 date/time types to ISO8601 strings.

```
Response creation = builder.build()
  .target("http://localhost:8080/my-api/v1.0/items")
  .request().accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  .post(Entity.entity(itemDTO, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
```

**Unexpectedly this request fails**, as the `LocalDateTime` contained in `ItemDTO` still gets serialized into a complex JSON object.

**N.B.: my REST API is perfectly able to deserialize ISO8601 string into LocalDateTime**

**N.B.: the code making the POST request works perfectly if not run inside a container (i.e. LocalDateTime gets serialized into ISO8601)**

Answer (score 0):

> *"the code making the POST request works perfectly if not run inside a container "*

Most likely the `JacksonJsonProvider` you are registering with the client is not the one being used. In the container, RESTEasy already has a Jackson module that is automatically registered with the client, and this is the one being used.

Instead of configuring the `ObjectMapper` and passing it to the provider, what you can do instead is use a `ContextResolver`. The provider will lookup this resolver and get the `ObjectMapper` from there.

```
@Provider
public class ObjectMapperResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public ObjectMapperResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        // configure mapper
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> cls) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Then just register the resolver with the client.

```
ClientBuilder builder = ClientBuilder.newBuilder()
        .register(ObjectMapperResolver.class)
```

If this *is* the case as I suspect, where there is already a JSON provider being registered automatically behind the scenes, then you will not need to register another one.